# Find a number in a set that is not equal to sum of any other numbers

Tags: summation

Given a set of nonzero real number S= $\{d_1,\cdots, d_N\}$, can I find a number $d_e \in S$ such that there does not exist $d_m,d_j\in S$ such that $d_e = d_m+d_j$ ? Assume $m$ and $j$ can be equal and $m,e,j$ denote the indices with $e\neq m,j$.

Comment: This depends a lot on $S$. What are the constraints?

Comment: S has finite number of elements, if it helps. S can be any sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true for any set of real numbers with a positive minimum. If $S\subseteq\Bbb R$ and $0<x\in S$ such that for all $y\in S, y\ge x$, then for any $y,z\in S$, $x\le y<y+z.$

This is false for the set $S=A\cup(A+1)$ where $\{-2,1\}\subseteq A$. If $x\in S$, then $x\in A$ or $x-1\in A$. In the first case, $x+1\in S$, so $x=(x+1)+(-1)$ is a decomposition, otherwise $x-1\in S$, so $x=(x-1)+1$ where $1\in S$.

Comment: What if S has negative numbers?

Comment: @widapol In the first paragraph I am making an example where the property is true. The step $y<y+z$ would no longer be guaranteed if $S$ had negative numbers. In the second paragraph I give a counterexample, that is, a set such that every two numbers is decomposable into two other numbers in the set.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out examples. However, we need to find a number that cannot be decomposed into any two other numbers in the set. Assume these two other numbers can be equal.

Comment: Thanks! An obvious example is the set $\{-2, -1, 1, 2\}$

Comment: @widapol And the counterexample also shows that $\{-2,-1,1,2,\dots,N\}$ is also closed under decompositions, so there are sets of any size $\ge4$ that are closed under decompositions.

Answer (score 0):

Not always.

Let $S= \{1, 2, 2^2, ..., 2^N\}$ and consider the case when $d_e = 1$.

Comment: What I mean is S can be any sets, not just a set we choose.

Comment: I think you misread the question. The OP asks whether it is possible to find a $d_e$ which is not the sum of two elements of $S$. So your example is not a counterexample.